# Does Redstone start sequence involve a key?

Tags: launch, history

After discussing the [*Key to start* (Ключ на старт) command during Soyuz launch sequence](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/do-any-spacecraft-use-carkeys), I decided to look at the historic lineage of the key and the command.

Gradually moving backward through [R7 ICBM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4LVqi7sMVw#t=25m50) to [R1 (the first large Soviet ballistic missile, a replica of V2/A4)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDhFdGLz2i4#t=14m47) historic videos I see that the launch sequence doesn't change a lot.

That made me go a bit further back in history... and voila:

The [V2 site states](http://www.v2rocket.com/start/deployment/procedure.html) that the A4 rocket launch sequence involved the **"Schlüssel auf Schießen!"** order. That is *Key to launch*.

Now, [the dear Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGM-11_Redstone) states that the *PGM-11 Redstone* rocket is a direct descendant of V2. Moreover, it was designed by the group of german engineers led by von Braun himself.

So the question is: ***does the Redstone launch sequence involve the key and an equivalent of "Schlüssel auf Schießen!" command***?

The bonus question is: does the [Dongfeng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongfeng_%28missile%29) launch sequence involve the key and the command? The first Dongfeng rockets were licensed copies of R2 and other Soviet rockets.

Comment: The Redstone transcript is a rare thing, but I have found [this one](http://www.mercury-redstone3.com/?page_id=24). What is interesting here is that the final sequence really matches [the one of Soyuz quite well](http://orbiter-forum.com/showthread.php?t=10418). If there was a key involved it should have been used before the last several commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Redstone missile firing procedures are described [here](http://www.myarmyredstonedays.com/Photos/page8/fm_6_36.html). According to [Table XVII](http://www.myarmyredstonedays.com/pdf_folder/fm_6_36_08.pdf), p.125, the operator shall "At X-0 minutes, depress FIRE **switch** and hold for 1 second".

So no, there's no key.